# xCode Throwing Random Linking Error?

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors

I use xCode to develop in C++ for my CS courses at college. I have no no problems with it so far. However, I have hit an error that I can't figure out within xCode.

Here is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "shortestpath(double const* const*, int, int, double*, int*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<int, int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, int> > >)",     referenced from:
  _main in main.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am doing some simple implementation of the Bellman Ford algorithm. My program is set up as follows:

main.cc - takes a .txt file of a graph in and sends it to my readGraph function.
readGraph.cc/.h - takes the graph file and reads it into an adjacency matrix and pulls out other necessary information
bellmanFord.cc/.h - performs the bellman ford algorithm on the graph.

My main file looks like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include "bellmanford.h"
#include "readfile.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    //check the command line length
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        //print the error
        cout << "Not enough command line arguments!" << endl;
        //return to exit with error
        return 1;
    }



    //open the graph file
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(argv[1]);


    //get the length
    int length;
    fin >> length;


    //make the references to send
    double** matrix;
    vector<pair<int, int>> pairVector;
    double* dist;
    int* prev;

    //make the matrix, and lists for bellmanford
    readfileTOMatrix(fin, matrix, length);
    readfileTOpairs(pairVector, matrix, length);
    make_Prev_and_Dist(prev, dist, length);



    shortestpath(matrix, length, 0, dist, prev, pairVector);


}
```

The error is occurring at the bottom on the call to shortestpath (which is the only function in bellmanFord.cc/.h). If I comment this out, it runs fine. I have checked and double checked, but I am pretty sure everything is set up correctly.

I understand that I could get around this with a make file I think....but is there anyone to correct this in xCode?

Here is the error details:
[image: error detail]

Comment: "xCode Throwing Random Linking Error?" - certainly not, at most the linker (Xcode is just an IDE).

Comment: Select the Build Phases tab for your target.  Expand the section that lists sources to compile and make sure your source that implements `shortestpath` is in there.

Comment: You'll need to include the defintion of `shortestpath()` into your project. Given that you haven't shown it although it is the obvious cause of the problem I assume you just haven't included it into your project.

Comment: Yep, I'm guessing the module that implements that method has not been included in the build.

Comment: @PhillipMills I checked there, and it lists main.cc, readfile.cc and bellmanford.cc (where the shortestpath function is defined)

Everyone else - "shortestpath" has a prototype in bellmanford.h which is included in bellmanford.cc where the function is written. 
And then, as you can see in the included code, bellmanford.h is included in the main.cc file.

Comment: @jangoforhire Are you sure the object files are specified in the correct order during linkage?

Comment: @H2CO3 Where would I check this?

Comment: @jangoforhire check the command line. I don't know how can you watch that in Xcode specifically (since I don't use Xcode), but I'm sure that's logged somewhere to the console.

Comment: If you open up the Log Navigator (speech balloon icon on top of the left view in Xcode), you should be able to select a build and then tell it you want to see "All Messages".  Do you see it compiling bellmanford.cc?  (It wouldn't be a prototype or include problem or else you wouldn't get as far as linking.)

Comment: @PhillipMills
Yes it is compiling, here is a screenshot of the Log Navigator. dl.dropbox.com/u/58059700/Random/error.png Its throwing a warning about it though...

Comment: I suspect the prototype of `shortestpath` doesn't match its definition.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes you were right, I had a very small discrepancy between my .h and .cc. Just forgot one "&"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very small discrepancy between my .h and .cc. Just forgot one "&" in the prototype that was missing in the actual declaration. All working now!